# Simulation: Problem with normals and Align Euler to Vector

Tags: normals, instances, simulation-nodes

I have a problem with the align Euler to vector, In a simulation, I am distributing some points on a grid, then use instance on points to have some cube to follow the bending grid.
The problem is that the Align Euler to Vector node isn't behaving the way I would expect and make the cube jiggle (instead of following their initial position) and their rotation flicker. I'm probably missing something which must be related to the simulation because if i replicate the same set up without using simulation it works correctly.

[Here is .blend file](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/c2p3wcjab6s27f14ldvyg/Simulation-Euler.blend?rlkey=6vbplym7e8fgwltnr42viqiti&dl=0)

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: since we don't see what happens in your bend geometry i would recommend providing your blend file so we know what you did and it will attract more people.

Comment: Yes sorry, I just added a link to the .blend file

Comment: i am not sure...if you set the switch to false - it works as intended, ....or not?

Comment: Yes, in this .blend file, when the switch is set to false this is how I would expect it to work, but as mentionned it is not a simulation, and I need it to work within a simulation.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is caused by the cubes sliding down and changing which faces the normals are sampled from. When the cubes reach face boundaries, they start to abruptly alternating between the two faces of the boundary.

One solution is to simply subdivide the geometry on which you sample normals, so there's less normal difference between neighboring faces:

[image]

[image]

Here's a faster solution: find out where the center of the bend is, and just align to it:

[image]

I think this could be done without raycasting, but your custom group is intimidating. If at any point you calculate the radius, then the center is just radius above origin…

Comment: and a much faster solution: align euler to the vector towards the center of the (closing) cylinder

Comment: Thank you, it kind of works better by subdividing but the cubes still jiggle a little bit.
About aligning euler to the vector towards the center of the (closing) cylinder, how would you achieve that? Thanks!

Comment: @JulesGuérin you need to calculate where the center of the bend is, but with your current setup I'm not willing to analyze it and see where to get it from… Could be derived from long edge angle and short edge length… A yet another alternative is to convert one loop to a curve and sample that curve's normal…

Comment: btw, by jiggle you mean rotations, not them stopping, right? That would be another problem.